# Angular v17 control flow for loop on select control throwing error with effect

Tags: for-loop, select, effect, angular17

control flow @for on select-option control is throwing ctx is not defined error when looping through an array and bind data to that array in an effect.

Same code worked fine with *ngFor

**ERROR ReferenceError: ctx is not defined**

loop through an array using @for & bind data to option control to display data in dropdown.

Comment: Updating Angular v17.0 to v17.1 has fixed the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.